# Why does my demo app on Heroku only show the "Welcome Aboard" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Note:** I have spent the morning carefully checking the similar questions on this subject but it has not helped.

**My Question**

I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby-on-Rails tutorial. The first demo app runs nicely. It shows "Welcome Aboard" and when I add /users it runs the demo app.
I pushed it to Heroku and it runs there but only shows the Welcome Aboard page.Adding /users gets "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.". I did not change any routes. It seems I should be able to view my demo app at this point on Heroku. I'm surprised because the tutorial is very thorough.

**Further Experiments**

I deleted `public/index.html`. And removed it from git and committed it and verified with `git status`. When I try to open `localhost/3000` I get "Routing Error" as expected. When I add /users, the demo app works as expected. I did not change routes.rb. I was not instructed to in the tutorial.

Now I push to Heroku and open my application there I now get "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."  That seems right. The same as if I opened `localhost/3000` when running locally.
But when I add '/users' at Heroku I still get the page error.
Do I need to add a route? This is not mentioned in the tutorial (or I overlooked something).

Thanks for help for this newbie to Rails.

**More Info**

I did add a route to point to `users/index` which now makes my localhost version open right up to the application without having to manually add `users` onto the URL. But when fully committed and pushed to heroku I still get a page error.

Here is the output from rake routes:

```
~/Documents/demo_app: rake routes
users       GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
new_user    GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user   GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
user        GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
root                                         users#index
```

Comment: One mistake I made was forgetting to run "heroku run rake db:migrate"

Comment: Can you do `rake routes` on your terminal and show us what you get?

Comment: I just ran the rake migrate command given above and I still get a pager error. I also have added a route that works locally to go straight to users without me having to add '/users' to the URL. Here is the output from rake routes (I used 'Answer' so it will format correctly)

Comment: Actually I added it to my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

run your application

```
# in your terminal write
heroku logs -e production
```

it will display error in your terminal, so that you can easily understand.

Comment: Thank you for helping with this. After the two migrates I ran my app and still get page not found. Trying to run your logs command gets this error: `Invalid arguments: "-e" and "production"`. Running logs without those two arguments gets a long sequence or steps that don't reveal anything obvious to me. There is a "Deprecation" warning like this: `DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins` but that sounds safe for the moment. Should I post the logs output ? Perhaps there is something there that I am missing.

Comment: Everything is working. My number one newbie error was that I was in a new rails application directory but I had created a new stack, My bad. In addition the Warning about plugins is because any file in the plugins folder has to be a legitimate plugin. I removed that file from git and the warning is gone. Thanks for being there with helpful words.

Comment: The above comment should say "but I had **NOT** created a new stack." Once I created a fresh cedar stack on Heroku for my new rails app everything worked.